# Recursive and recursively enumerable sets.

Tags: logic, computability

I am trying to solve the following problem :

Let $A = \{n \in \mathbb{N} : \mbox{ for } \mbox{ all } x\in \mathbb{N}, \mbox{ if } {\phi}_{n}^{1}(x) \mbox{ is } \mbox{ defined } \mbox{ then } {\phi}_{n}^{1}(x) \leq 10 \}$.

1) Prove that $A$ and $\mathbb{N} - A$ are not recursive.

2) Prove that $\mathbb{N} - A$ is recursively enumerable and use it to explain why $A$ is not r.e.

I am not very familiar with this area. So any help would be really appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What does $\phi$ mean here ?

Comment: It is a fuction from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$

Comment: Surely $\phi^1_n$ is an enumeration of the recursive functions $\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$...

Comment: Yes exactly! Do you have any hints for this problem?

Comment: What's your definition of a recursive function? There are a lot of equivalent definition out there and depending on which one you know, a given proof might be unrecognizable to you unless we work with similar notions.

Comment: @Stefan I am mostly familiar with Kleene's definition : A "partial recursive function" of nonnegative integers to be any function f that is defined by a noncontradictory system of equations whose left an right sides are composed by (1) function symbols (2) variables for nonnegative integers (3) the constant $0$ and (4) the successor function $S(x)= x+1$. I also know the definition of $\mu$-recursive function. Do you work with these definitions?The exercise does not ask to solve it using a specific definition of the recursive function, so if you have any other def. to reccommend,please do so.

Comment: Do you know of any examples of non-recursive sets? Are you familiar with Post's theorem characterizing a recursive set $A$ in terms of $A$ and $\mathbb{N} \setminus A$?

Comment: Yes, i know that the so-called creative sets are non-recursive sets. No, unfortunately I am not familiar with Post's theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1) you can either use [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem) or prove it directly by showing that some non-recursive set, for example, $K = \{n \in \mathbb{N} \mid \varphi_x(x)\!\downarrow\}$ is $m$-reducible to $\mathbb{N} \setminus A$, i.e., there exists a recursive function $f(x)$ such that $n \in K \Leftrightarrow f(n) \in \mathbb{N} \setminus A$. Consider the following function
$$
g(x, y) = \begin{cases}
11,& \text{if } \varphi_x(x)\!\downarrow,\\
\uparrow,& \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$
By s-m-n  theorem there exists a recursive function $f(x)$ such that $\varphi_{f(x)}(y) = g(x, y)$. We also have
$$
n \in K \Leftrightarrow \exists y\, (\varphi_{f(n)}(y) = g(n, y) = 11) \Leftrightarrow f(n) \in \mathbb{N} \setminus A. 
$$
This shows that $K \leqslant_m \mathbb{N}\setminus A$, and since $K$ is not recursive, so is $\mathbb{N}\setminus A$. The complement of a recursive set is recursive, so $A$ also can't be recursive.

For 2), Post's theorem says that a set is recursive if both itself and its complement are recursively enumerable. So if we show that $\mathbb{N}\setminus A$ is r.e. we are done. Showing that $\mathbb{N} \setminus A$ is r.e. depends on your definition of an r.e. set. We have
$$
n \in \mathbb{N}\setminus A \Leftrightarrow \exists x\,
(\varphi_n(x)\!\downarrow \wedge\ \varphi_n(x) > 10) 
\Leftrightarrow f(n)\!\downarrow, 
$$
where $f(n) = \mu z(z = (z_1, z_2) \wedge \varphi_n(z_1)\!\downarrow \text{in $z_2$ steps} \wedge \varphi_n(z_1) > 10)$. Intuitively, the program for $f(n)$ at step $m$ runs $\varphi_n(0), \dots, \varphi_n(m)$ each for $m$ steps and checks the condition $\varphi_n(x) > 10$ for convergent computations. If it finds one it halts, otherwise it keeps searching. This shows that $\mathbb{N} \setminus A = \mathrm{dom}\,f$ for some recursive $f$ and hence this set is r.e.

Comment: Your answer is very understanding and in detail. It helped me a lot to understand the whole idea of this problem. Thank you so much!